# EWS C# ExchangeService.MoveItems Issue

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm having an EWS MoveItems issue that I hope someone can help me with. With 1300 emails in the sent folder, I call the MoveItems method to move them ALL to a back-up folder and only a subset of the items get moved! Looking for a pattern, I recorded the following test numbers:

Test #1: Init Count: 1300; Actual # Moved: 722

Test #2: Init Count: 1300; Actual # Moved: 661

Test #3: Init Count: 1300; Actual # Moved: 738

With each test case my logging output shows that 1300 were found and passed to the MoveItems method, however, checking the Sent Items folder shows that not all 1300 were moved (as indicated in the above tests).

Here's a snip of my code:

```
...
do
{
    ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset);
    findResults = service.FindItems(folder, emailFilter, view);

    Logger.Write("Email count on this page to be archived: " + findResults.Items.Count);

    foreach (Item email in findResults)
    {
        itemIds.Add(email.Id);
    }

    offset += pageSize;
}
while (findResults.MoreAvailable);

Logger.Write("Total email Ids to be archived: " + itemIds.Count());

if (itemIds.Count() > 0)
{
    Logger.Write("Archiving emails...");
    service.MoveItems(itemIds, folder5.Folders[0].Id);
    Logger.Write("Archive call complete.");
}
else 
{
    Logger.Write("No emails found to archive.");
}
...
```

All of this is wrapped in a try/catch block. No errors are caught.

The only other interesting item worth noting, is that the time between the "Archiving emails..." log and the "Archive call complete." is always within a second or two of being 1 minute. Possibly indicating a time-out on the call? Here's a snip of my log:

```
8/15/2014 4:29:43 PM - Information - Archiving emails... 
8/15/2014 4:29:44 PM - Information - Creating search filters...
8/15/2014 4:29:48 PM - Information - Email count on this page to be archived: 1000
8/15/2014 4:29:49 PM - Information - Email count on this page to be archived: 300
8/15/2014 4:29:49 PM - Information - Total email Ids to be archived: 1300
8/15/2014 4:29:49 PM - Information - Archiving emails...
8/15/2014 4:30:51 PM - Information - Archive call complete.
8/15/2014 4:30:51 PM - Information - Email archival completed without errors
```

I'm pretty much at the end of my rope, so I appreciate any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: I wonder if the call ends up returning  fewer items than `pageSize`. `FindItemsResult` has a `NextPageOffset` property. Can you use that for the next `offset`, instead of incrementing it by `pageSize`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634962(v=exchg.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue while working with EWS. I'm not sure what the "correct" solution is, but my workaround seemed to work. I profiled the move and it seemed to do fine moving a few hundred items at a time. Try moving ~250 in each call to MoveItems.

Comment: ChrisG, thanks for your suggestion. I may end up using your work-around. I'll give original post some more time. Hopefully someone will post a "correct" solution for both of our sakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try processing the ServiceResponses that come back when you run the MoveItems method eg

```
            if (itemIds.Count() > 0)
        {                
           ServiceResponseCollection<MoveCopyItemResponse> Responses =  service.MoveItems(itemIds, folder5.Id);
            Int32 Success = 0;
            Int32 Error = 0;
            foreach (MoveCopyItemResponse respItem in Responses) {
                switch (respItem.Result) {
                    case ServiceResult.Success: Success++;
                        break;
                    case ServiceResult.Error: Error++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error with Item " + respItem.ErrorMessage);
                        break;
                }                  
           }
            Console.WriteLine("Results Processed " + itemIds.Count + " Success " + Success + " Failed " + Error);
        }
```

That will tell you what's going on and why some of your moves have failed. I would suspect its throttling so as Chris suggested drop your batch size down. In the past when I've written stuff to do large moves between Mailbox and Archive I went for 100 item batch size and never had a problem. When I set the batch size too large I saw time-outs and throttle errors.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip on checking the ServiceResponses!